# Applet's Packages attribute is null JRE7u21

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-2, package

With a JavaFX applet :

The javascript object I get with document.getElementById("APPLET_ID") has no Packages attribute under Windows.
I run my tests on Windows XP with IE8, FF and Chrome up to date, but it's the same problem under windows 7.

Under Ubuntu with JRE 7u7 x64, no such problem.

Here is my test code :

```
package test;

import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

private JSObject js;
TextField tf;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
js = this.getHostServices().getWebContext();
HBox hb = new HBox();
Scene s = new Scene(hb, 400, 400);
tf = new TextField("MAIN");
primaryStage.setScene(s);
hb.getChildren().add(tf);
primaryStage.show();
runTest();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}

void runTest(){
new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Platform.runLater(
new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
tf.setText("" + js.eval("document.getElementById('applet_id').Packages == null"));

}
}
);
}
}).start();
}
}
```

Displays "false" under Ubuntu JRE7u7x64 and "true" under Windows and Ubuntu JRE7u21 with all browsers.

As the JavaFX2 deployment doc page tells I'm doing it the right way, it looks like a JRE bug. What do you think about it ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_javascript.htm .

Filed on Jira :  https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30732

Comment: Probably best to file an issue in [the JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com)

Comment: Tested under Ubuntu with JRE7u21x64 : the Packages attribute is null too.

Please, this is a serious problem, could someone just notice me if this is a all new bug, a deprecated access to Packages (didn't see any clue for this), or a known bug ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posted on Oracle's Forums : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2542189

Comment: Only clue of a change for JRE7u21 on this horrible page : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html
The change is that when mixing priviledged code and sandbox code, warnings should prompt (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html ).
With all my tests, there's no warning appearing. Looks like I'm missing a permission to access Packages, even when requesting all-permissions security policy in my JNLP file.

Comment: I'll stop post here to only update the JavaFX Jira bug report. I'll just post the answer to my question when any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks it's an expected change since 7u21 : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html
This Packages attribute no more works.

So if you need callbacks from your JS to your applet, you must access directly it's methods.

And use the Trusted-Library manifest attribute to avoid warnings.

But you can't do what you want when using Trusted-Library. For example, if you use Axis2 webservices.

So you'll have to do it with Trusted-Only manifest attribute. But this forbids you to call methods from JS.

Simple workaround :
Have a thread periodically checking a JS callback queue and treat them. It's painful, horrible POJO but it works.

So to Oracle :
THANKS

- for updating online doc
- for announcing major changes made in minor releases
- for making web integration so easy.
- for adding other security checks in u25 that result in 20 seconds gray screen latency

Do you know Adobe ? Heard they have pretty good stuff... I'm pissed.